# Test an NTP server from android command line

Tags: android, shell, time, command-line, ntp

I have read that what I am trying to do can be done on linux systems using the ntpdate command:

ntpdate -d time.google.com

which should return a valid time but should not if you give it an address that isn't an ntp server.

Problem is... the ntpdate command is not available on android.

How can I do this from an android system?

Comment: Possibly related: [How can I set a server address to automatically sync my device time?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/135950/3573)

Comment: Yes I am able to set the time server.  I want to validate that what the user enters as their time server actually IS a time server before I set it.

Comment: You might want to clarify what type of Android device you are trying to modify. Consumer devices are limited without root (see my link). If you are interested in how Android determines time or for a Custom ROM, see Android Open Source Project documentation on [time](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/time)

Comment: It is a custom build device that we have rooted and are running our own custom rom on it which is an offshoot of nougat.  Is there some linux command (which is available on android) that can be used to accomplish this?